# wordpress SWF format not supported

Tags: wordpress

I have two swf video in WordPress site.but both the videos does not supported in chrome.
I tried lot of plugins.but not any one plugin is supported for run these videos in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you have to put your swf video in your root directory. Then you can check your plugin/widget etc. whatever you have used to video auto play. I have used a Easy Flash Embed wordpress plugin and it is implementing WordPress shortcode which is creating widget

short-code emample/;

```
[swf src="http://test.info/Exp_credit.swf" width=300 height=410]
```

In the place of `test.info` you can put your own server address.
 And after that your problem should be solved and your video will be played automaticaly in chrome.